# While creating the circle 2 dots appeared and I need to delete the dots

Tags: inkscape, shapes

while creating a circle in inkscape, 2 dots appeared in the figure and they turned my circle into Pac-Man. How can I delete these dots?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new ellipse/circle, make sure to select the icon from the top toolbar to make the full ellipse/circle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works now.